# Is a 40109 fit for 3V3 <=> 5V level shifting?

Tags: digital-logic, level-shifting

I have checked [couple](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/fn31/fn3196.pdf) of [datasheets](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/schs099b-127269.pdf) for [40109](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/SGSThomsonMicroelectronics/mXwwwy.pdf) and although they specify "Supply Voltage Range" as min: 3V, max: 18V, none of the other tables specify values for < 5V.

Can I safely order these chips for use in a ([Bluetooth master](http://www.electrodragon.com/w/index.php?title=BC04)) 3V3 <=> 5V (ATtiny) level shifter application? And how can I conclude that from the datasheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **unidirectional** data flow, although there will be shifters more suited to lower voltages, you should be fine with this chip. On page 6 of the [ST datasheet](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/SGSThomsonMicroelectronics/mXwwwy.pdf), there is a High voltage vs Low Voltage graph which indicates a minimum combination of ~3V for Vcc and 5V for Vdd:

[image: CD40109]

If you are using both Rx and Tx, then you will need a bidirectional level shifter, such as the [ADG3304](http://uk.farnell.com/analog-devices/adg3304bruz/translator-4ch-bi-dir-14tssop/dp/1078228). Or you can use two unidirectional ICs, as discussed in the comments.

Comment: RX and TX are separate pins on the BT master, and I need them both for proper operation. So basically you say: use another level shifter. I'll take the 40109 from my wish list then.

Comment: I'm starting to realize how to read the Vcc and Vdd. Does it make a difference if I use two separate IC's? "- Input Signals can Exceed Both VCC and VDD".

Comment: Yes, you could use two unidirectional ICs in this case, since the individual lines themselves do not change direction. Just arrange them for the correct direction in each case. There are quite a few example UART level shifting circuits out there, the most basic use a couple of transistors.

Comment: FYI: added an URL to details on the BT module to my question.

Comment: @jipp - thanks, it seems very similar to the HC-05 BT modules I have used in a few designs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SN74LVCC3245, as it is ideal for converting 3.3V to 5V and vice vesa.

Comment: Please tell us *why* it is ideal.